# CSS stylesheet not linking to my html page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where my css does not affect my html. I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8AJjz/)
It worked when I wasn't trying to connect an external stylesheet and used style tags,
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

btw i tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
```

and it did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot link my CSS to my HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469199/cannot-link-my-css-to-my-html)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are linking it in your 'head' section of the HTML such as this:

```
<head>
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
```

Also be sure to close the tag and that the style sheet you are linking is named 'index.css'

**Edit:**

HTML is split up into two main section tags: body and head. In a normal HTML page, the structure is like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code I referenced at the beginning of this answer should be placed into the head section of the HTML page.

Comment: I did that but even in the fiddle where no linking is invloved it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by split up? where's this section?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. If the CSS is not responding, it's probably having something to do with the CSS you're actually trying to use.

Comment: Also, here is proof that the CSS on your page actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/8AJjz/1/

Comment: Here is your JsFiddle with the 'input , #button' in the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/8AJjz/2/

Comment: I am having similar problem too. Got  any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are linking to simply `index.css` worries me. Is `index.css` in your site root? If so, specify that:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">`

Comment: The slash is not necessary if it is in the same folder.

Comment: Right, but that's a very common mistake to forget the leading slash. Absolute locations are always safer than relative.

Answer (score 1):

As stated also by BuddhistBeast, check to make sure it's in between the head tags:

```
<head>
<link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
```

Also check that you are referencing it correctly. If it is all in one folder, then

```
<link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is correct.

If it's in its own folder, named "css" for example, it should be written as:

```
<link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You put `#button` instead of `input, #button` in the css.