# Cannot link my CSS to my HTML

Tags: html, css, encoding, stylesheet, rel

I'm at the last of my wits here. I've searched through dozens of websites trying to find the answer to this issue, but I have yet to find a solution that helps me.

Here is the top section of my HTML, linking to my CSS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <title>Sample Page</title>
    </head>
```

For some reason, when I preview my .html file on my browsers, my CSS code is not taken into account.

Just to clear things up a bit, I've already made sure the following are not the reasons for my issues:

- My CSS code worked just fine when it was in the HTML within the style
  tags. It only stopped working once I put it into its own .css file.
- There are no `<style>` tags on my .css file.
- The rest of my HTML is correctly formatted. I have the `</html>` tag and the `<body>` tags.
- I've tested this page on Chrome and Firefox, and even on a different computer's Chrome. I've even tried running them as an Administrator.
- I've checked to confirm that my browsers are not set to Quirks Mode.
- I've tried multiple DOCTYPE headers, none have shown any signs of working.
- The .css name is correct, and the file location is correct. Both the index.html and the style.css are in the same folder.
- I've tried these lines of code in different orders, different formats, I've even tried other peoples' code and nothing works.
- I've checked the source code for the page on my browser, and clicking the style.css link leads straight to the file.

The only lead I've gotten is that I clicked "Inspect Element" on my page in Chrome and checked the "Resources" tab, where the HTML is found under **Frames>(index.html)>index.html** and the CSS is found under **Frames>(index.html)>Stylesheets>style.css**. If I click index.html, the body is blank, but if I click style.css, the body is, strangely enough, a bit of Chinese text.

Here is a sample of a style.css I've tried:

```
body
    {
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Even with the CSS as simple as this, it still won't work.

Please help.

**EDIT:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOXIy.png

**Read my post, you guys. They're in the same folder. The different paths are in the "Inspect Element" mode in Chrome, not in my folders themselves.**

Comment: Are you sure that the `style.css` is in the root of the project? It's probably just the path to the css. Where do you have your css file?

Comment: "the HTML is found under Frames>(index.html)>index.html and the CSS is found under Frames>(index.html)>Stylesheets>style.css"... Doesn't this just mean that your CSS is NOT in the same folder as your index.html?

Comment: Both the css and the html are in the same folder, and are the only files in the project.

Comment: @xgeorgekx that's how it appears under the "Inspect Elements" menu in Chrome, not in the folders themselves.

Comment: You sure the are in the same folder? You mention above that they are not.

Comment: Look at the network tab in Chrome devtools and ensure that `style.css` is getting downloaded properly. Also, please provide a directory listing of the directory containing `index.html`.

Comment: Probably it will not help, but try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` without slash at the end of tag

Comment: Hey torazaburo, how would I ensure that style.css is getting downloaded? I checked the Network tab and it's just blank besides the toolbar at the top.

Comment: @Jozef yup, I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Open Elements in chrome with F12 and find your tag and click on href. If it loads it is loaded ok, if not your path is bad.

Comment: @Jozef Here's a picture of the results: http://i.imgur.com/KOckjL4.png It seems like it can find the style.css, but for some reason it's reading it as a bunch of Chinese characters. Clicking the index.html gives me the code I wrote for that file. You can also see the exact directories in this image.

Comment: Open css file in some editor for example Notepad++ and change encoding of file to UTF-8

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website please, i'll take a quick look

Comment: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), open file, in main menu find Encoding->Convert to UTF-8.Look again in Encoding and option Encode in UTF-8 should be checked and save file. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Jozef That did it! Thanks so much! I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[Jozef Dúc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3937482/jozef-d%c3%bac) wrote in the comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469199/cannot-link-my-css-to-my-html#comment39746477_25469199), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469199/cannot-link-my-css-to-my-html#comment39746561_25469199)):

> Open css file in some editor for example Notepad++ and change encoding of file to UTF-8

> Notepad++, open file, in main menu find Encoding->Convert to UTF-8.Look again in Encoding and option Encode in UTF-8 should be checked and save file. Hope it helps :)

This is what solved it for me.

Comment: george, you may accept your own answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [your screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469199/cannot-link-my-css-to-my-html#comment39746383_25469199)

> [image: Developer tools show chinese characters when inspecting the CSS]

it looks like you have bad encoding in file.

So first add

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

to your HTML.

Then you must change encoding in CSS files. Open the file in some editor (I recommended [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)). In Notepad++, find <kbd>Encoding</kbd> in menu and in submenu choose option <kbd>Convert to UTF-8</kbd>. Now, look again in "Encoding" and "Encode in UTF-8" should be checked, then save the file.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and this is what worked for me. i realized the .html and .css files where all in one single folder that's why it wasn't working. to solve this,

open the project folder(the folder that contains your html files), in this folder, create another folder called 'styles'. Finally, place the .css file in the style folder and run your site again.

this worked for me. hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line `<meta charset="utf-8">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
```

Comment: It's under Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature that they're found under different folders, because that's where they place CSS files for websites.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it either.

Comment: This is going to set the charset for the page, not any CSS files.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes that is correct. My next suggestion was for OP to change the file. Somebody else suggested it before though.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Ensure that **CSS** is enabled in your browser.

**1.1 Firefox & Chrome:** I recommend using Chris Pederick's **[Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)**, it is a CSS menu (third from left if you have a newer version where the text labels got KOed).

**1.2 Safari:** ensure the **Develop** menu is visible (Edit-->Preferences-->Advanced) and then ensure that *Disable Styles* is *not* checked.

**1.3 Opera (Real Opera, 12.5 and earlier):** Tools-->Preferences-->Advanced [tab]-->Content-->"Style Options" [button]-->Presentation Mode [tab] and ensure that "Page Style Sheet" is checked.

**1.4 Internet Explorer:** Go to Tools-->Options and ensure that under the "Security" tab that the zone (either Local Intranet (if loading the page from your hard drive) or Internet (if you're uploading to a server and then loading it in a browser) are set to Medium-High.

**2.** Ensure that your HTML and CSS files do *not* have a BOM (Byte Order Mark) which is created by Notepad and other Microsoft text editors. You can disable the BOM by using Notepad++ or SuperEdi in the *Save As...* dialog, you will need to do so for both. **NEVER USE MICROSOFT TEXT EDITING TOOLS FOR WEBSITES!**

**3.** Running a local server? Check either the Apache access logs or the Developer **Network** tab to ensure the style.css file isn't coming up as 404.

Answer (score 0):

My link tags work also without the / at the end of the tag. you can try that.
and you can get to element ispect and that to console. maybe the console can tell you what's wrong.